# ROC AUC for average and geometric mean of two models

Tags: roc, auc

Suppose I have two binary classification models built on the same dataset.

One has ROC AUC of 0.86, another one has ROC AUC of 0.92.

What will be the ROC AUC for the average of two models and their geometric mean?

I'm lost with this question cause when I try to unfold the ROC curve with number of true positives and false positives of each model and what their combination will result in and account for thresholds it makes just too many variables.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "unfold the ROC curve". But I have the feeling you won't get anywhere with it, as you just don't know which observations will be the positive and negative ones, and what the mean of the observation would be. You'll need to go back to the model, calculate its average, and then do the ROC curve...

Comment: That's the only info given in the problem. Assume there are no actual models, only their ROC AUC's. By "unfolding" I mean trying to understand how the TPR and FPR change when we combine two models together trying to estimate TPR and FPR from ROC of a model.

Comment: I think that's impossible. Because the result will depend on the data itself. Maybe someone will be able to write down a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks @Calimo. I'm also lost, but that's what I see people asking during DS interviews.